# MagicalRecord keypath

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I am using magicalrecord and have my properties mapped to the json `details.slots`.

My JSON looks like this

```
"details": {
    "startTimestamp": "2014-01-13",
    "endTimestamp": "2014-01-16",
    "employeeId" : 176,
    "slots": [
    {
        "numberOfAppointments": 0,
        "numberOfSpots": 1,
        "isReserved": 0,
        "startTimestamp": "2014-01-13 08:00:00",
        "endTimestamp": "2014-01-13 08:05:00"
    },
    {
        "numberOfAppointments": 0,
        "numberOfSpots": 1,
        "isReserved": 0,
        "startTimestamp": "2014-01-13 08:05:00",
        "endTimestamp": "2014-01-13 08:10:00"
    },
    {
        "numberOfAppointments": 0,
        "numberOfSpots": 1,
        "isReserved": 0,
        "startTimestamp": "2014-01-13 08:10:00",
        "endTimestamp": "2014-01-13 08:15:00"
    },
    ....
```

I was wondering is there an easy way to map a field to a field up a level? IE I can use `my.object.property` to drill down but is there anyway if my import is importing the `slots` array to easily add the employeeId to each object? Slots can be as little as 600 records to up to a couple thousand.

The only solution I can think of is looping through every slot and manually adding it before I run the magical record import. **Is anyone familiar with another, easier way to get this done?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could achieve this with the current framework is to implement the method

```
- (BOOL) importDetails:(id)data;
```

In your entity. MagicalRecord importing will look for this method and call it based on your core data property name if it's implemented. This would mean that you're basically rewriting the import code for the entire array, but you'd have access to the data you're after. Not ideal, but still possible.